# Capture pixels and create new image

Tags: python, image, multidimensional-array, jython, pixel

I am trying to "capture" all of the pixels in an area of an image (the area determined by the width and height of the rectangle object drawn on the display), and create a new image containing the pixels captured from the original image.

The problem is that when I run it I get index out of range/coordinate out of bounds errors. I tried printing the length of a chord_pixels array (to get the number of rows, which should be the same as the width of the rectangle), and length of chord_pixels[0] (to get the number of columns, which should be the same as the height of the rectangle), and it turns out that often these are very different than the height and width of the new image (which is the same size as the rectangle the pixels came from). The difference is often by more than 100. I have pored over this for hours, and tried a ton ideas, including very silly ones. Now I offer this to the internet.

```
img = Icon("name")
d = Display("name", 1000, 1000)
img.setSize(1000,1000)
d.add(img)

beginX,beginY,endX,endY = 0,0,0,0
chord_pixels = []
rect = Rectangle(0,0,0,0)

def beginRectangle(x,y):
   global beginX, beginY
   ...
   beginX, beginY = x, y

def drawRectangle(x,y):
   global beginX, beginY, endX, endY, rect
   ...
   if rect in d.getItems():
      d.remove(rect)     
   endX, endY = x,y
   rect = Rectangle(beginX, beginY, endX, endY, Color.BLACK, False, thickness=3)
   d.add(rect)    

def endRectangle(x,y):
   global beginX, beginY, endX, endY, img 
   ... 
   getPixelsInRectangle(img, beginX, beginY, endX, endY)

def getPixelsInRectangle(image, x1, y1, x2, y2):
   global chord_pixels
   row_pixels = []
   chord_pixels = []
   for y in range(y1,y2):        
      for x in range(x1, x2):    
         pixel = img.getPixel(int(y),int(x)) #getPixel(col, row)
         row_pixels.append(pixel) 
      chord_pixels.append(row_pixels)
      row_pixels = []

def captureChordPixels(key):
   global chord_pixels, rect
   chordWindow = Image(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight())
   for col in range(chordWindow.getHeight()):
      for row in range(chordWindow.getWidth()):
         chordWindow.setPixel(col, row, chord_pixels[col][row])

d.onMouseDown(beginRectangle)
d.onMouseDrag(drawRectangle)
d.onMouseUp(endRectangle)
d.onKeyDown(captureChordPixels)
```

Comment: To be clear, all you want to do is get a sub image from an original image given x,y,w,h of the sub image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're okay with using PIL it's pretty easy.

`crop()` accepts a 4 item tuple defining the left, upper, right, and lower pixel coordinate. (x1,y1,x2,y2)

```
im = Image.open("image.png")
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
x2 = 500
y2 = 100
croppedImg = im.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))
croppedImg.save("new-img.png")
```

Comment: Wow. I feel like I wasted so much time. (Because I really did). Thanks!